# Can a Bangladeshi enter India by air from third country?

Tags: air-travel, legal, international-travel, india, bangladeshi-citizens

I am from Bangladesh, and I have an Indian tourist visa, which I received from the Indian High Commission in Bangladesh. At this moment I am in Bhutan. Now I want to enter India by air. Is it possible? And will I face any problems when I come back from Kolkata to Dhaka?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the past there were restrictions on Bangladeshi ciitzens entering India by air, but [these are no more](https://www.dhakatribune.com/bangladesh/foreign-affairs/2017/07/25/india-removes-entry-exit-restrictions-bangladeshis/).

You can enter or exit India via any of the 24 international airports or two land checkpoints indicated, in addition to any port of entry printed on your visa. There is no restriction regarding the country you traveled from when entering, or the country you travel to when leaving.

> Ahmedabad; Amousi (Lucknow); Amritsar; Bagdogra; Bangalore; Calicut; Chandigarh; Chennai; Cochin; Coimbatore; Dabolim (Goa); Delhi; Gaya; Guwahati; Hyderabad; Jaipur; Kolkata; Mangalore; Mumbai; Nagpur; Pune; Trichy; Trivandrum and Varanasi. The two integrated check posts are Benapole-Haridaspur and Darshana-Gede. Previously, Bangladeshis could only travel through the ports indicated on their visas.